plpgsql logic for displaying progress through a for loop
I have functions and procedures that contains loops and can run for several hours. As a result I want to implement some sort of progress monitoring (so I know they are actually making progress) similar to tqdm in python or progress in R.
I have got a rough working version but wanted help to make the logic cleaner. The example task below is to read each integer in task_list and do an upsert to store the double of the integer in the second column:
CREATE TABLE example.task_list (
  intt int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  double_intt int
);

INSERT INTO example.task_list VALUES
  (1, NULL), (2, NULL), (3, NULL), (4, NULL)
RETURNING *;

CREATE OR REPLACE function example.doloop()
  returns void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   begin_time timestamptz = clock_timestamp();
   num_tasks_done int := 0;
   average_time_per_task interval := null;
   tasks_remaining int;
   f record;
   time_to_do interval;
BEGIN
   SELECT count(*) INTO tasks_remaining FROM (SELECT DISTINCT intt from example.task_list where double_intt is null);
   raise notice '%: Starting. We have  [%] tasks to do.', clock_timestamp(), tasks_remaining;
   FOR f IN (SELECT DISTINCT intt from example.task_list where double_intt is null)
      LOOP
      begin_time = clock_timestamp();
      raise notice '%: Putting in [%]', begin_time, f.intt;
      raise notice '%:   We have done [%] jobs and have [%] jobs remaining. It will take %', clock_timestamp(), num_tasks_done, tasks_remaining, average_time_per_task * tasks_remaining;
      INSERT INTO example.task_list (intt, double_intt) values (f.intt, 2 * f.intt)
      ON CONFLICT("intt") DO UPDATE
      SET double_intt = EXCLUDED.double_intt;
      time_to_do = clock_timestamp() - begin_time;
      raise notice '%:        Finished. It took : %', clock_timestamp(), time_to_do;
      /* Do calculations for time remaining */
      average_time_per_task = ((coalesce(average_time_per_task,'0 minutes') * num_tasks_done) + (time_to_do)) / (num_tasks_done+1);
      num_tasks_done = num_tasks_done + 1;
      tasks_remaining = tasks_remaining - 1;
      END LOOP;
  END;
$func$;
select example.doloop();

This does work as intended with the function raising notices to describe its progress and estimated time to completion. The shortcomings are:

I need to do separate SQL queries. One to get the list of tasks to be completed for the monitoring and once to loop over.
The logic/variables for the function and the logic/variables for timekeeping are all mixed together and it is hard to see what is going on.

Is there a way to 1) define a list of tasks once and 2) encapsulate the timekeeping logic and raising notices logic separately.
It does not work but it would be great to be able to write loops like the following and get the timekeeping for free:
CREATE OR REPLACE function example.do_loop_with_tqdm()
  returns void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   f record;
   task_list_generator any := make_generator(SELECT DISTINCT intt from example.task_list where double_intt is null)
BEGIN
   FOR f IN (task_list_generator)
      LOOP
          INSERT INTO example.task_list (intt, double_intt) values (f.intt, 2 * f.intt)
          ON CONFLICT("intt") DO UPDATE
          SET double_intt = EXCLUDED.double_intt;
      END LOOP;
  END;
$func$;


Create a function that you pass the lists elements in the for loop to do the work and raise the notices? Make the notice texts into string variables e.g begin_time varchar '%: Putting in [%]'.

I dont think that would simplify it much though. I would need to still have in this function the state variables (num_tasks_done, average_time_per_task, etc)  and pass them to the other function that would do the notice raising. I guess I would also still need to do two select statements to get the tasklist.

One way to avoid running the same SQL twice might be something like:
declare
    tasks int[];
    i int;
begin
    select array_agg(DISTINCT intt order by intt) 
    into tasks
    from example.task_list 
    where double_intt is null;

    for i in 1 .. cardinality(tasks) loop
        -- i-th task is tasks[i]
        raise notice 'Task % out of %', i, cardinality(tasks);
    end loop;
end;

The idea here is:

Use an array to store the list of tasks (bonus: make the execution order deterministic by using e.g. order by intt)
The number of tasks is therefore cardinality(tasks)
The loop counter enumerates the tasks from 1 to cardinality(tasks), in the order in which they were aggregated in array_agg(), so no need to keep track of the number of tasks done

This also gives us the option of decoupling the logic of deciding which tasks should be executed (and in which order) from the procedure that actually does the job.

Thanks this is a bit cleaner but I dont love it as a solution. I would ideally like to export all of the logic for raising notices (together with basic runtime analytics) to another namespace/function like you could get with a class or generator function called each loop. Also in my actual problem I use a query to get records and then use f.col1, f.col2, etc in the loop. So I cant just reduce it all down to an array of ints.

It might just not be possible in plpgsql
